# A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'DMS.Models.DMS_Company'

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to call Webservice (.asmx) to populate Datatable.
But the service throws **404 Error**. Find Code Below...

**Web Service**

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)] 
    public void getCompanyData()
    {
        var dms_company = _db.DMS_Company.Include(d => d.DMS_state).Include(d => d.DMS_Login);
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(dms_company));
    }
```

**RouteConfig**

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        //routes.IgnoreRoute("{page}.aspx/{*webmethod}");
        //routes.IgnoreRoute("{allaspx}", new { allaspx = @"..aspx(/.*)?" });
```

I tried all the routes commented above but same error.

[image: Error Screen Shot]

Comment: Please post the contents of CompanyData.asmx, which should start with "<%@ WebService Language="C#"", which should be in the root folder, and confirm that the web service code is in a file called CompanyData.asmx.cs.

Comment: I suspect either CompanyData.asmx and the .cs file are not in the root folder of the site or the .asmx file has a name other than CompanyData.asmx.

Comment: @JamesMcLachlan Thanks for the reply I solved this issue by adding
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*x}", new { x = @".*\.asmx(/.*)?" });
in RouteConfigFile

Comment: @JamesMcLachlan After this I am facing a new error

**A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'DMS.Models.DMS_Company'.**

in the below command

**Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(dms_company));**

Comment: The circular reference issue should probably get its own question, but a little Googling might save you even posting that question.